# how to set date field to 3 months back

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a radio button for fetching the record of last 3 months from database. I am using a radio button for the user to select the date range, for three months back. 
How do I set the value of the radio button, to eaxctly 3 months back?

```
 <input type="radio" id="test7" name="thismonth" value="<?php echo date("Y-m", strtotime("-3 months"));?>" />
```

This sets the value for only one month but is there way I set the value to exactly three months back?

Comment: I see no attempt of accessing your database in your code...

Comment: @Akhil, The question look like for MySQL part but you are showing HTML

Comment: I just confirm that is there any way set the value of radio button from previous 3 months to current month?

Comment: The issue is in your query, show us your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
<?$effectiveDate=date('y-m-d');
$effectiveDate = strtotime("-3 months", strtotime($effectiveDate)); ?>
<input type="radio" id="test7" name="thismonth" value="<?php echo effectiveDate?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php 
    $value = $_POST["thismonth"];

// note : name attribute for your input field is 'thismonth', should be something else.

    $query = "SELECT *columns* FROM *table* WHERE *date_column* BETWEEN '".$value."' AND '".date('Y-m')."' ";
    ?>
```

Comment: This is a dangerous way of creating queries. Please use prepared statements / parameterized queries.

Comment: @Christiaan this was just for demo purpose to make him understand.